# Styling only first letter from an array of strings in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been using `react native table component` in my project. I this project I have shown data in table rows and columns like

```js
tableData: [
        ['a 1234', 'b 4332', 'c 5433'],
        ['a 4556', 'b4554', 'c 4777']
]
```

But I want to style these `a,b,c` with different color not like the numbers. How can I style like that?

Now, I am styling like this:

```html
    <TableWrapper style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Cols data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
     </TableWrapper>
```

Comment: You can get the first element of the string as tableData[0][n].charAt(0) if it's always like shown above.

Comment: You could use CSS, and use the `::first-letter` pseudo element. Have you tried anything so far? What does your React script render to?

Comment: Can you please show how can I do this styling in React Native. I have tried but got no luck in conditional styling. @DavidsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: I know I can get the first element but I was asking how to style that in react natiive @PatrikAlexits

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CSS style `textTransform: 'capitalize'`. The `text-transform` property controls the capitalization of text.

```
<TableWrapper style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Cols data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
</TableWrapper>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
 text: { 
   textTransform: 'capitalize'
 }
})
```

if you want the some index letter use diffent style. you can do like the following

```
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>
   {tableData[i].charAt(0)}
    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {tableData[i].subString(1,tableData[i].length)}
    </Text>
</Text>
```

for the string split you can use `subString()` or `charAt()` method.

Comment: This capitalizes the first letters but how can I change the color of them? @Lenoarod